# Error Connect Database Sqlite in Mule Connector

Tags: sqlite, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I want to  connect and select database Sqlite on Mule AnypointStudio. But it error. Please help me. Thanks all. 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite
here my code:

```
    @Processor (name="select" ,friendlyName ="select")
    public void  select() {
        ArrayList<Story> list =  new ArrayList<Story>(); 
        String sql = "select * from chat";
        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
                Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

               // loop through the result set
               while (rs.next()) {
                   Story s = new Story();
                   s.setStory(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("user_chat"),rs.getString("bot_chat"));
                   list.add(s);
               }
           } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
     for (int i =0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i).GetID() +"| "+ list.get(i).GetUserChat() + "| "+ list.get(i).GetBotChat() +"\n" );


     }
    }
    private Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // SQLite connection string
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\data.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Please provides details (stack trace, exception message, anything useful) so people can help you.

Comment: This is error when I run project. My connector can not find Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"), but I test in Mule Project it success.  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Comment: Ok. From what I understand you have this issue with a Mule Connector project. Are you using Maven?

Comment: I don't use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure You have valid jar/driver in your project classpath.**

Open new Mule Project in Studio, and then follow these steps to add/create a datasource in mule flow:

a. Import the driver

b. Create a Datasource,

c. Create a Connector that uses our Datasource, and finally

d. Create a simple flow that uses our connector.

It seems you are missing driver jar in project classpath.

**How to Import the Driver?**

Once you have the jar file(you can download jar respective to sqllite from some repo ,eg- [maven_repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7)), the next steps are very simple:

In the Package Explorer,

Right-click over the Project folder

Look in the menu for Build Path > Add External Archives…

Look for the jar file in your hard drive and click Open.

Now you should see in the package explorer that the jar file is present in “Referenced Libraries.”

This will allow you to create an insta
nce of the Object driver you will need.

Comment: Thank for your help. I done it. But I want to import jdbc in Connector Project. It error :(

Comment: I import sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar  in Mule Project that ok. But when import to Connector Project error

Comment: Please paste the error you are getting and code where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a classpath issue. If you are using Maven with your project, simply add the dependency in your `pom.xml` (and right click on your project > Mule > Update project dependencies):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you understand how Maven works and how to manipulate your pom.xml file. [Maven getting started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) and [POM Introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) might help.

If you are not using Maven, you need to manually import the dependency in your classpath. @Malesh_Loya answer should help.